# Structural search of certain object initializations in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, slf4j, structural-search

I'm trying to use the structural search in IntelliJ to find all occurences of object array initializations with arbitrary array elements but I can't seem to get it right:

The quite simple search template that I'm using is:

```
new Object[] { $DONT_CARE$ }
```

It does not pick up the occurences that I'm looking for. In fact it mostly finds totally unexpected occurences like the following:

```
private final static int[] SOME_VARIABLE = { 0, 10 };
```

What I expected to find was lines similar to the following (the interesting bit is the new Object[] - part):

```
log.debug("Some log statement param1[{}], param2[{}], param3[{}]", new Object[] { param1, param2, param3 });
```

A simple "Find in path" with the following "Text to find" works just fine:

```
new Object[] {
```

I must be doing something wrong here. Does anyone have an idea why I don't get the expected result?

Best regards,
Ben

P.S. As a side note for the interested reader: I'm doing this because I'd like to upgrade the slf4j - framework in our project and I want to replace all occurrences of the previously required syntax for multiple log params using an Object-array:

e.g. `log.debug("Some log statement param1[{}], param2[{}], param3[{}]", new Object[] { param1, param2, param3 });`

with the following code using a variable parameter list:

`log.debug("Some log statement param1[{}], param2[{}], param3[{}]", param1, param2, param3 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have hit a bug in Structural Search (see [this bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138047)).

However for your particular problem you can also use the *Redundant array creation* inspection. This inspection reports array creation expressions that are passed to variable argument methods and it has a quick fix which fixes the problem.

Another option/workaround is to include the method call in the Structural Search query:

```
$log$.$debug$($string$, new Object[] { $expr$ });
```

$expr$: minimum count: 0 maximum count: unlimited

$log$: expression type: Logger

Comment: The _Redundant array creation inspection_ works nicely and was exactly what I was looking for. Your proposition for the adjustment of the structural search query does not only work nicely as well but it also taught me something new about IntelliJ. Here goes my advice for fellow programmers stumbling across this problem: Keep in mind that **there are additional settings for the structural search variables**  (hint: Edit variables...) that may need to be adjusted to fit your needs.

Comment: I went ahead and took my own advice and now even the initial search query I started with found the occurences. Just to be fair: It also still found the undesired occurences. :)